# meaning of permutation raised to a power, another permutation

Tags: notation, permutations, symmetric-groups

I am unable to find any reference on the meaning of $\pi^\psi$, where $\pi$ and $\psi$ are two permutations of the set $\{1,2,3, \ldots ,n\}$.
E.g, $(1,2,3,5,4)^{(2,3,5)}$

Incidentally the package GAP provides this operation, but the manual says nothing about this.
Thanks

Comment: I've seen this notation used to mean conjugation, but it is not quite standard. Where did you see it?

Comment: If you plug in your example do you get $(1,3,5,2,4)$?

Comment: It's conjugation, and in group theory this is commonly used notation. In GAP this is introduced in the beginning of its Tutorial in [A First Session with GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/tut/chap2.html) - for GAP beginners, reading at least its first several chapters is **very much recommended** before going further.